# Keeping one value per group in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` like so:

```
A       B       C       D       F                    

test    mobile  US      2.0     2.0 
test    mobile  US      2.0     2.0 
test    mobile  US      2.0     2.0 
test    mobile  US      2.0     2.0 
test    mobile  US      2.0     2.0 
prod    mobile  US      1.0     10.0    
prod    mobile  US      1.0     10.0    
prod    mobile  US      1.0     10.0    
prod    mobile  US      1.0     10.0    
prod    mobile  US      1.0     10.0    
prod    mobile  US      1.0     10.0
```

I want to keep only the first value per group `A, B, C` so that it look like this:

```
A       B       C       D       F                    

test    mobile  US      2.0     2.0 
test    mobile  US      0       0   
test    mobile  US      0       0   
test    mobile  US      0       0   
test    mobile  US      0       0   
prod    mobile  US      1.0     10.0    
prod    mobile  US      0       0   
prod    mobile  US      0       0   
prod    mobile  US      0       0   
prod    mobile  US      0       0   
prod    mobile  US      0       0
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for mask and pass to [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with list of columns for set `0`:

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['A','B','C']), ['D','F']] = 0
print (df)
       A       B   C    D     F
0   test  mobile  US  2.0   2.0
1   test  mobile  US  0.0   0.0
2   test  mobile  US  0.0   0.0
3   test  mobile  US  0.0   0.0
4   test  mobile  US  0.0   0.0
5   prod  mobile  US  1.0  10.0
6   prod  mobile  US  0.0   0.0
7   prod  mobile  US  0.0   0.0
8   prod  mobile  US  0.0   0.0
9   prod  mobile  US  0.0   0.0
10  prod  mobile  US  0.0   0.0
```

If need more dynamic solution for replace all columns to `0` without `cols` list use:

```
cols = ['A','B','C']
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=cols), df.columns.difference(cols, sort=False)] = 0
print (df)
       A       B   C    D     F
0   test  mobile  US  2.0   2.0
1   test  mobile  US  0.0   0.0
2   test  mobile  US  0.0   0.0
3   test  mobile  US  0.0   0.0
4   test  mobile  US  0.0   0.0
5   prod  mobile  US  1.0  10.0
6   prod  mobile  US  0.0   0.0
7   prod  mobile  US  0.0   0.0
8   prod  mobile  US  0.0   0.0
9   prod  mobile  US  0.0   0.0
10  prod  mobile  US  0.0   0.0
```